# Checkbox disappear

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my checkbox inline with the text using display:block and display:inline. When I use this the checkbox disappear and don't show the full size.

I have tried to read and find other ways to solve this but I'm stuck.

Is there any other way to get the checkbox in same line as the text?

Please help a student :)

```css
grid_newsletter  {
 background: #ffeb3a;
  
}

.grid_newsletter .text {
 text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 41px;  
}

.grid_newsletter input {
    width: 380px;
    border-top: transparent;
    border-left: transparent;
    border-right: transparent;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.grid_newsletter input[type="checkbox"] {
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline;
  
}

.grid_newsletter .checkbox_terms {
 margin-top: 23px;
 display: block;
 
}

.grid_newsletter .content {
    text-align: center;
    padding:  70px 55px 30px 60px;
    display: inline;
}


.grid_newsletter .text_box_newsletter {
 background: white;
    width: 495px;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.grid_newsletter .text_box_newsletter p {
 padding-top: 39px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.100em;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_newsletter">

    <div class="content">

        <div class="text">Newsletter!</div>

        <form>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="förnamn">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="e-post">
        </form>
        
        
      
        <div class="checkbox_terms">
           
              <input type="checkbox" name="confirm">
              
               <span class="save">Jag godkänner att mina uppgifter lagras.</span>
               <span class="terms"><a href="#">Läs mer om vår hantering av data och vår integritetspolicy här.</a></span>     
    
   </div> <!-- checkbox_terms --> 

        <div class="text_box_newsletter">
            <p>skicka</p>
        </div>
        

</div> <!-- content -->
</div> <!-- grid_newsletter -->
```

`

Comment: You should use a label around the checkbox and wrap the first span, so when click on that span the wrapped checkbox will become "checked".

Comment: It works if you simply remove all styles for the input from the stylesheet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` or `display: inline` together with `vertical-align: middle` on the involved elements.

```css
grid_newsletter  {
 background: #ffeb3a;
}

.grid_newsletter .text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 41px;  
}

.grid_newsletter input {
  width: 380px;
  border-top: transparent;
  border-left: transparent;
  border-right: transparent;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.grid_newsletter input[type="checkbox"] {
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline;
}

.grid_newsletter .checkbox_terms {
 margin-top: 23px;
 display: block;
}

.grid_newsletter .content {
  text-align: center;
  padding:  70px 55px 30px 60px;
  display: inline;
}


.grid_newsletter .text_box_newsletter {
 background: white;
  width: 495px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.grid_newsletter .text_box_newsletter p {
 padding-top: 39px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.100em;
}

.vAlign {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_newsletter">

    <div class="content">

        <div class="text">Newsletter!</div>

        <form>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="förnamn">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="e-post">
        </form>

        <div class="checkbox_terms">

            <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" class="vAlign">
              
            <span class="save vAlign">Jag godkänner att mina uppgifter lagras.</span>
            <span class="terms vAlign"><a href="#">Läs mer om vår hantering av data och vår integritetspolicy här.</a></span>     
    
  </div> <!-- checkbox_terms --> 

        <div class="text_box_newsletter">
            <p>skicka</p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- content -->
</div> <!-- grid_newsletter -->
```

Answer (score 0):

When You use the display block you have to give it a width and height and float left so it will act line inline for that part.

You can also use the height according to your need .
I hope this is what you were looking for .

```css
grid_newsletter  {
 background: #ffeb3a;
  
}

.grid_newsletter .text {
 text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 41px;  
}

.grid_newsletter input {
    width: 380px;
    border-top: transparent;
    border-left: transparent;
    border-right: transparent;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.grid_newsletter input[type="checkbox"] {
 
 border: 2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height:15px;
 float: left;
}

.grid_newsletter .checkbox_terms {
 margin-top: 23px;
 display: block;
 
}

.grid_newsletter .content {
    text-align: center;
    padding:  70px 55px 30px 60px;
    display: inline;
}


.grid_newsletter .text_box_newsletter {
 background: white;
    width: 495px;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 27px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.grid_newsletter .text_box_newsletter p {
 padding-top: 39px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.100em;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_newsletter">

    <div class="content">

        <div class="text">Newsletter!</div>

        <form>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="förnamn">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="e-post">
        </form>
        
        
      
        <div class="checkbox_terms">
           
              <input type="checkbox" name="confirm">
              
               <span class="save">Jag godkänner att mina uppgifter lagras.</span>
               <span class="terms"><a href="#">Läs mer om vår hantering av data och vår integritetspolicy här.</a></span>     
    
   </div> <!-- checkbox_terms --> 

        <div class="text_box_newsletter">
            <p>skicka</p>
        </div>
        

</div> <!-- content -->
</div> <!-- grid_newsletter -->
```

Answer (score 0):

use `vertical-align:middle` as shown below for textbox:

```
.grid_newsletter input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;/*Newly added*/
}
```